# What jar contains com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionCheckerImpl in Liferay 6.1.2?

Tags: liferay, wso2, single-sign-on

I am trying to follow http://liferaysatish.blogspot.de/2011/11/permissionchecker.html (which is basically a repost of another blog post).
I need to implement my own PermissionChecker to be able to support an SSO server (check if the user has been authenticated). However, there article mentions com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionCheckerImpl, but there is no such class in whatever jars I was looking for it.

What I am trying to achive is to tie liferay's internal security to an external SSO Server (wso2). If there is another way to achieve this, I would love to try it.

I was trying with AdvancedPermissionChecker and SimplePermissionChecker, but I become endless redirects using them.

regards and thanks
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the latest Liferay does not have this file anymore. You should search for it in the 5.0 version. And the JAR itself is in \ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\portal-impl.jar
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.0/javadocs/portal-impl/com/liferay/portal/security/permission/PermissionCheckerImpl.java.html

Comment: That was my thought too. So what to use instead? SimplePermissionChecker?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to implement my own PermissionChecker

I don't believe so. At least you can make your life easier if you integrate your SSO just like any of the already integrated 6 (or so) SSO systems, authenticating the current user to Liferay and then leaving the actual permission check to Liferay.

SSO is typically used for making sure the user is who they are, then redirecting to the application they're providing their services to. If you want to maintain permissions externally to Liferay, you're best of to use an LDAP and group your users there. On the Liferay side, map those LDAP users/groups to Lifeary-usergroup-memberships. Provide the required permissions/memberships for those usergroups and you're set. Implementing your own permission checking (which will also be used internal to Liferay) is one of the least maintainable ideas that I've ever heard of.

Comment: Hi Olaf, can you explain this comment a little more 
"At least you can make your life easier if you integrate your SSO just like any of the already integrated 6 (or so) SSO systems, authenticating the current user to Liferay and then leaving the actual permission check to Liferay."

Comment: Liferay integrates a number of SSO systems already. Thus your SSO is already available in Liferay, or it's supposed to be easy to integrate yet another SSO. If you go this route (use an existing anticipated extension point) your implementation is easier that when you rip out the permission system and implement it yourself.

Comment: "Liferay integrates a number of SSO systems already" what number? All I found was support for OpenSSO in an ancient version and some windows stuff. And a CAS Filter, but in a strange manner (checked the source code). Besides, even if Liferay integrates the SSO I understand that you still need to have the same users on both sides.

Comment: I didn't bother to count. CAS, NTLM, OpenSSO (with that OpenAM), Shibboleth... Some others use the same principles (e.g. header-based). IMHO enough to claim that yet another SSO integration will likely be easy (I've seen a number of them). They need the same users, yes. That's what LDAP is for. I'm just trying to point you to an easier maintainable solution than messing with Liferay's permission system. If you feel adventurous, go ahead and change permission checker. It's quite a central component though, thus I predict your implementation to be fragile. AFAIK all SSO is implemented in Filters

Comment: Hi Olaf, yes, you confirmed what I already seen, but still the problem remains, what do I gain from an SSO solution if I have to have same user's on both sides? So I will have no users on the liferay side. Anyway, if I have my users somewhere else, I will also have my roles and grants somewhere else, so how will liferay know if someone is allowed to execute a specific action?